# Copy files with same base name from multiple directories

Tags: bash, sh

I have a bunch of directories with files with the same basename.  I'd like to copy them with a different basename but in the same directory.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you please give a sample of your current directory structure, and the directory structure / filenames of your desired result?

Comment: I have a command which can outpus to stdout "A/B/myfile A/C/myfile D/E/myfile D/F/G/myfile" etc

Comment: and, for instance, would you want them to all go to A_B_myfile, A_C_myfile, D_E_myfile, etc.?  We understand you want them to wind up in the same directory, but how do you want the naming convention to work for them to not overwrite each other?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The directory structure is somewhat complex, which is why it's hard to answer that.  I want all of the copies to have a different basename.

In specific, these are CI configs for different C++ builds with different compilers.  So the basename may be ubuntu-cmake-gcc-debug (which already exists in each directory) and I want to make ubuntu-cmake-{clang,gcc}-{debug,release} in teh same directories which are copies, which I can then go in and edit by hand

Comment: You will need a small helper scrip that takes the full path to each file as its first parameter to essentially strip one component from the path at a time (and if more than one letter in that component, pick one character) and build a string to use as a prefix for the filename in the common directory and then copies (or moves) the original file to the new directory under the new name. Then look at `find /path/to -type f -name "myfile" -exec "/path/to/helper.sh '{}' \;"` (you must make `helper.sh` executable, or use `bash -c "/path/to/helper ..."` with find)

Answer (score 0):

Use string replacement:

```
for name in oldbase*; do
    mv -v $name ${name/#oldbase/newbase}
done
```

This means for example move oldbase123 to newbase123.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using dirname:

```
for file in `get_file_names`; do
  cp $file `dirname $file`"/newfilename"
done
```